# Connecting to HPQC from 64bit JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, hp-quality-center, com4j

While trying to cennect HPQC from a 64bit machine(having 64bit JAVA, and ECLIPSE), I am getting the below mentioned exception:

*Exception in thread "main" com4j.ExecutionException: com4j.ComException: 80040154 CoCreateInstance failed : Class not registered : .\com4j.cpp:153
    at com4j.ComThread.execute(ComThread.java:203)
    at com4j.Task.execute(Task.java:25)
    at com4j.COM4J.createInstance(COM4J.java:97)
    at com4j.COM4J.createInstance(COM4J.java:72)
    at com.qc.ClassFactory.createTDConnection(ClassFactory.java:16)
    at com.java.Test.main(Test.java:25)
Caused by: com4j.ComException: 80040154 CoCreateInstance failed : Class not registered : .\com4j.cpp:153
    at com4j.Native.createInstance(Native Method)
    at com4j.COM4J$CreateInstanceTask.call(COM4J.java:117)
    at com4j.COM4J$CreateInstanceTask.call(COM4J.java:104)
    at com4j.Task.invoke(Task.java:51)
    at com4j.ComThread.run0(ComThread.java:153)
    at com4j.ComThread.run(ComThread.java:134)*

PFB my code:

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    //QC url
    String url = "https://qc_link/qcbin";
    //username for login
    String username = "username";
    //password for login
    String password = "password";
    //domain
    String domain = "domain";
    //project
    String project = "project";

    ITDConnection itdc = ClassFactory.createTDConnection();

    System.out.println("Connecting");

    itdc.initConnectionEx(url);
    itdc.connectProjectEx(domain, project, username, password);

    System.out.println("Connected......");
}
```

}

The above code works fine for 32bit Java and Eclipse.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Parag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The COM API's are 32-bit only and cannot be accessed by a 64-bit process.  I have the same problem with .NET applications where I'm stuck in 32-bit until I can move to the REST API (which is bit-less) or host my COM-reliant code in an external process.

Answer (score -2):

This issue can be solved by registering all 3 .dll files in c:\Windows\SysWow64. instead of c:\Windows\System32.

Hope it might be helpful:)